# Why can't I get the search result using an app I made using Google App Script, even if I surely have the data?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

By following the instruction of [this website](https://www.bpwebs.com/create-web-forms-to-get-data-from-google-sheets/), I made a web app using Google App Script (GAS) which will display the search when a user enters a search term (e.g. order number, status, price) in the search window and the search is successful (The screenshot below represents what I expected). However, my app always returns 'Data not found!' even if the search term exists in the data. What am I missing, then?

[image]

## Components of the app

### Data

A spreadsheet that contains the exactly same contents of [the original spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/142FbylWc7109R0RsXQ42NuN_TFs-D3RTtIYJOSBR1QM/edit#gid=0)
(i.e. I copied the original contents and pasted them to my own spreadsheet to prepare the data)

### Index.html

I copied the code from
https://gist.github.com/bpwebs/dbbd96f8262e486c8f4c321ea0d3a95a#file-index-html
and pasted it to 'Index.html' in my own GAS project.

### Code.gs

I modified the original code on
https://gist.github.com/bpwebs/dbbd96f8262e486c8f4c321ea0d3a95a#file-code-gs
since the original code has an undefined variable (`Sheets` on [ln.19](https://gist.github.com/bpwebs/dbbd96f8262e486c8f4c321ea0d3a95a#file-code-gs-L19)) and cannot open the spreadsheet. I replaced the relevant code with `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` and `range.getValues()`.

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}
 
 
/* PROCESS FORM */
function processForm(formObject){  
  var result = "";
  if(formObject.searchtext){//Execute if form passes search text
      result = search(formObject.searchtext);
  }
  return result;
}
 
//SEARCH FOR MATCHED CONTENTS 
function search(searchtext){
  // var spreadsheetId   = '1p7fKVM7HA4Ikl8gYC2WesmHcIqAqJQWTfIuiqB4SyN4'; //** CHANGE !!!
  // var dataRage        = 'Data!A2:Y';                                    //** CHANGE !!!
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('The URL to my spreadsheet');
  var range = ss.getRange('Data!A2:Y');
  var data = range.getValues();
  // var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRage).values;
  var ar = [];
   
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
  return ar;
}
```

Comment: I can't be sure but if there are any dates in the spreadsheet row you need to convert them to string.

Comment: @TheWizEd I do not think that date values hinders the web app's functionality. Once I deleted the column that contained date (`ORDERDATE`) and replaced `ss.getRange('Data!A2:Y')` with `ss.getRange('Data!A2:X')`, but still the web app returned `Data not found!` when I searched for the order number `10251`.

Comment: From [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) "Most types are legal, but not Date, Function, or DOM element besides form; see description"

Comment: I think you need to put some `Logger.log` in your scripts to see where it is failing.  And 'alert' on return from the server to see what `dataArray` is.

Comment: Do you see more details about the error if you try going to your project in Apps Script and go to "Executions"?

Comment: Please provide debugging details: what is your search input. `getDispalyValues()` instead of `getValues()` should worker better because only string would be matched by `indexOf`.

Comment: `Sheets` is not a "variable" but the Google Sheets API. See [Enable the Google Sheets API advanced service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced).

Comment: @idfurw Replacing `getValues()` with `getDisplayValues()` solved the issue. I was searching the order number `10251`, for instance. Thank you for your comment. Would you want to make an answer post explaining the difference between the two functions?

Comment: @LorenaGomez I could not find any error of the app when I saw Executions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sheets API is used in the original code:

(See: [Enable the Google Sheets API advanced service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced))

```js
Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRage).values;
```

By default, the values are formatted and are strings.

(See: [ValueRenderOption](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption))

---

[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) performs exact match on each element and the passed value, where the **data type** has to be the same.

Your are now using https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues that unformatted values are returned (number as number and date as date object), which would **always return false** when `indexOf()` (exact match) is performed.

To get formatted values (string), use [`getDisplayValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues).